# Graphs: DFS visit and Java implementation

Tags: java, recursion, graph, depth-first-search

I'm trying to implement a recursive Depth-First Search for a graph in Java language.

**Assumptions**

- The graph is represented with adjacency lists.
- GraphSearchImpl is a data structure that stores the result of a visit.
- GraphSearchImpl contains arrays that store, for each vertex, start/end times, visit status (UNDISCOVERED, DISCOVERED, CLOSED), weight of the path etc etc..
- All vertices have a unique index mapped in a HashMap, where the String is a unique label for each vertex. I'm reading/writing arrays cells, for a specified vertex, using this index.

**Code**

```
    public void visitDFSRecursive(GraphSearchImpl search,VertexImpl u,Integer time) {
    int index = search.getIndexOf(u);
    search.status[index]=VertexImpl.DISCOVERED;
    time++;
    search.startTimes[index]=time;
    for (VertexImpl v: u.getAdjList()) {
        int adjIndex = search.getIndexOf(v);
        if (search.status[adjIndex]==VertexImpl.UNDISCOVERED) {
            search.status[adjIndex]=VertexImpl.DISCOVERED;
            search.parents[adjIndex]=u;
            visitDFSRecursive(search,v,time);
        }
    }
    search.status[index]=VertexImpl.CLOSED;
    time++;
    search.endTimes[index]=time;
    }
```

I'm calling this method like this, over a graph with just two nodes (A -> B):

```
g.visitDFSRecursive(search,sourceVertex,new Integer(0));
```

The output is the following:

-A starts at 1 ends at 2

-B starts at 2 ends at 3

It's obviously wrong, because the time interval of start/end of B must be included in the A's one, since B is a son of A in this graph.

I know the problem is that I'm not using time counter right.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `time` is a local variable, so when you increment it up in your recursion, the `time` for `A` is not affected. You should convert it to a global/static variable, or make an integer wrapper class and pass it through a mutable object.